# DrawerLayout conflicts with RecyclerView? RecyclerView fill the whole screen

Tags: android

I created an Activity using DrawerLayout which is attached in AndroidStudio.But When I used the RecyclerView, the RecyclerView filled the whole screen...?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/titleList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[The Button on the left top can't be used.Guess it was coverd by RecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYGPr.png)

dsajfhkjasldfkj

Comment: You don't want your `RecyclerView` there. You need to put it in the content `View`; i.e., the layout for the `<include>`. You probably have a `content_main` layout. It would go there.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout needs to be structured like this :

```
 <DrawerLayout>

   //Main View
    <RelativeLayout>

        //this will show in your main Content,


    </RelativeLayout>

  //Second View 

    <LinearLayout>

        //this will be seen on your drawerlayout

    </LinearLayout>
 </DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I am happy that you were able to fix your problem follwing my answer. However it would be great if you upvote and/or mark mine as answer if it helped you :)